# Google sheets formula to add two separate products of greater than or equal to

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to figure out (if it's possible) what formula I need to be able to add one range that is equal to or greater than and multipled by X amount to another range that is equal to or greater than and multipled by another amount.

Here's the basic formula;
=E22*IF(E22>=13, 148, IF(E22>=12,118,))

So I need to add the product of 'E22>=13, 148' to the product of 'E22>=12,118'

Any changes I tried, I just got an error.

Comment: Hi, can you add an example of inputs and the expected output? It will be easier to help

Comment: If I have 1-12 apples that range group is X number times 118
If I have 13+ apples that range is X number time 148.
I need the 1st range group total (lets say it's 12, so 1,416)
Plus the 2nd range group total (let's say it's 13, so 1,924)
So it adds both totals together

Comment: in your basic formula, you have an if statement with this condition `E22>=12` but in your comment it's more like `E22<13`. Can you add a sample of your tab in your question ?

Comment: Sorry I mean E22<=12